# Would code review be a good place to ask for a review of a presentation?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I have a presentation on AMD and I need a few good reviews on it.  Would this type of "review" be a good fit for the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

We review code. We don't review anything else.